# how to add clearcase components in a integration stream in a correct way

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Sorry for the  long post .

In our project we have following components

1. `xyz_design` (a.v,b.v files)
2. `xyz_project` ( soft link to xyz_design directory, link to xyz_verif directory and some other directory)
3. `xyz_libs` (lib1.v , lib2.v files)
4. `xyz_verif` (ver1.sv,ver2.sv files)

Now we planned  to create two project & two different integration  streams  in following manner.

`Chip_design_xyz` (Z_chipxyz_design) (Below are the components)

- `xyz_design` (modifiable component)
- `xyz_project` (modifiable component)
- `xyz_libs` (modifiable component)

`Chip_verification_xyz` (Z_chipxyz_verif) (below are the components)

- `xyz_Verif` (modifiable component)
- `xyz_project` (non modifiable component)
- `xyz_libs` (non modifiable component)
- `xyz_Design` (non modifiable component)

Where `Z_chipxyz_design` and `Z_chipxyz_verif` is a Rootless component  in their  respective integration stream.

All the components have foundation baseline with `BL0` i.e `BL0_design`, `BL0_verif` etc. with `chip_design_xyz` stream having `z_chip_design_bl0` and `chip_verification_xyz` having `z_chip_verif_bl0` as composite baseline.

Now suppose in `chip_verfication_xyz` project we make changes in file `verif1.sv` file and create a new baseline called `z_chip_verif_bl1` and recommended it.
Note: Here we have made changes to only `xyz_Verif` folder and have not changed anything in `xyz_design` folder.

Now in `chip_design_xyz` people make changes in `a.v` file and releases a new composite `baseline z_chip_design_bl1`.

Suppose we  take newly released baseline and rebase our verification stream.
Will this create any conflicts?

Because we have a composite baseline `z_chip_verif_bl1` (Recommended baseline of our stream) where it has components `xyz_design` which has baseline `BL0_design` and  now when we rebase to `z_chip_design_bl1`, we have `xyz_design` pointing to `BL1_design` baseline.

Does this setup  raise composite baseline conflict when we try to rebase ?

Answer (score 0):

By rebasing the foundation baseline of the rootless component, you would change and replace one baseline by another.

That is allowed only if the component (rootless or root-based) has not yet produced new baselines created on the stream you are using to rebase (here `chip_verification_xyz`).

Here however, you did create a new `z_chip_verif_bl1`. So you can no longer just rebase: you need to deliver changes from one integration stream (`chip_design_xyz`) to `chip_verification_xyz`.

I might mixed-up the rebase destination stream, but the idea remains the same: here an inter-project delivery might be recommended.

Comment: thanks fro quick reply.  But  when we take design stream baseline and try to rebase that baseline in our Verification stream so will this create conflict because we have xyz_design as non modifiable component in our stream. Also whether following setup for our stream is more recommended where we have z_chipxyz_verif (composite component) with only one component xyz_verif and remove all the other components under z_chipxyz_verif and rebase our stream with design baseline (z_chip_design_bl1) .

Comment: @Sat A non-modifiable *rootless* component would still get a new baseline if one of its dependency baseline changed. But if in your case it did not, then you should be able to rebase and simply replace one set of baselines by another by changing the composite component foundation baseline: no conflict expected there.